# QML Menu remains highlighted/open after clicking and selecting a MenuItem

Tags: qt, menu, qml, menuitem, menubar

In my QML application (QT 5.11.3 on Debian) I have the following menu code:

```
ApplicationWindow {
   id: window
   visible: true

   height: 600
   width: 400

   menuBar: MenuBar {
      id: menuBar
      Menu {
         id: menuFile
         title: "File"

         MenuItem {
            text: "Open"
            onClicked: {
               menuFile.dismiss()               // no effect?
               mainPage.openNew()
            }
         }

      }
   }
}
```

Now the problem is, that once I click the menu entry `File` to bring up the menu, and then click anywhere other than `File` again (e.g. outside of the menu, or a menu entry), the `File` entry in the menu bar remains highlighted, like this (right-most):

[image]

This is especially annoying since in order to open the menu again after this happens, you actually have to click `File` **twice** (once to "close" from the previous opening, second time to open it again).

Do I have to add some special code to manually "close" the menu after "usage"? This feels pretty weird. I have also added `menuFile.dismiss()` hoping it would close the `File` menu as I would manually do when clicking it again, but it does not change anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue (Qt 5.15.2 on Windows). What is the behaviour if you comment both lines in the `onClicked` ?

Comment: Well, its the same as if you would just click somewhere in the window (thereby auto-closing the menu), with the same effect that `File` remains highlighted.

Comment: That's very strange... Do you have any chance to move to a newer Qt version?

Comment: Probably not, I'm on the companies machine which is managed by the admins.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but are you importing `import QtQuick 2.12` and 
`import QtQuick.Controls 2.15` I am also unable to reproduce your issue in Qt 5.15.2 on Windows. I guess this might also be something weird with Debian.

Comment: I am importing `import QtQuick 2.11` and `import QtQuick.Controls 2.4` which seems to be the newest I can import, anything else above this will result in errors complaning that the module version is not installed. (and, to be honest, since working with QT I never found out how I can find out available versions for the built-in modules other than trial&error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running into the same issue on 5.11.3.  I believe the issue is fixed in later versions by https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-71583.  The issue does not occur on 5.12.3.